# How to disable default routing in CakePHP 3.x for specific .php file?

Tags: php, cakephp, ckeditor, cakephp-3.0

I'm using CKEditor in CakePHP 3.x.
It ajax-calls upload.php script to upload image files.

How can I disable default (controller/action) routing just for this one script?
It lays in webroot/upload.php

My (incorrect) guesses are:

$routes->connect('/upload.php', ['/upload.php']);

$routes->redirect('/upload.php', '/upload.php', ['status' => 302]);

in config/routes.php

Comment: There should be no need to do anything at all. By default all files in the `/webroot/` folder can be accessed directly. If that doesn't work, then there's something wrong with your URL rewriting config.

Comment: You are right @ndm (as always). It wasn't Cake. It was a wrong path to upload.php in CKEditor config. Thx!